# Parsing HTML to find data beaurtiful soup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract key information on [this page](https://shop.caremar.it/main_acquista_1_corse_00_ajax.asp?l=it&data=25/02/2019&portoP=1&portoA=4&form_url=ticket_s1_2) using beautiful soup.
In particular I would like the `.booking-item`/s within  `.booking-list`.

The desired outcome is:

```
[{"FERRY TYPE": "Traghetto", "DEPARTURE TIME":"06:40", "DEPARTURE DATE": "25/02/2019","DEPARTURE PORT": "CAPRI","ARRIVAL TIME":"06:40", "ARRIVAL DATE": "25/02/2019","ARRIVAL PORT": "NAPOLI PORTA DI MASSA"}]
```

I've tried the following

```
caremar_departures_table = soup.select('.booking-item .row')
    for div in caremar_departures_table:
        caremar_timetable.append({
           "FERRY TYPE": div[5].b.text,
           "DEPARTURE TIME": div[12].h5.text
            ...
        }
```

but I get error

```
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 5
```

Comment: The dict 'div' has no key with the value 5.

Comment: The resulting `div` in `caremar_departures_table` is of type `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` and not subscriptable. The `[...]` notation are used to get a `attribute` from a `bs4.element>`. E.g. `<div myAttr='test'>`: usage `div['myAttr'] == 'test'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the site with spesific tags. Its more easy and readable . I did it for you check it.

```
from urllib import  urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = "https://shop.caremar.it/main_acquista_1_corse_00_ajax.asp?l=it&data=25/02/2019&portoP=1&portoA=4&form_url=ticket_s1_2"

page = urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

div = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'booking-item'})
caremar_timetable = []
for a in div:
    ferry_type = a.find('b').text
    departture_time = a.findAll('h5')[0].text
    departure_date = a.findAll('p')[0].text
    departure_port = a.findAll('b')[1].text
    arrival_time = a.findAll('h5')[1].text
    arrival_date = a.findAll('p')[2].text
    arriva_port = a.findAll('p',attrs={'class' : 'booking-item-destination'})[1].text
    arriva_port = " ".join(arriva_port.split())

    caremar_timetable.append({
        "FERRY TYPE": ferry_type,
        "DEPARTURE TIME": departture_time,
        "DEPARTURE DATE" : departure_date,
        "DEPARTURE PORT" : departure_port,
        "ARRIVAL TIME" : arrival_time,
        "ARRIVAL DATE" : arrival_date,
        "ARRIVAL PORT" : arriva_port

    })


print caremar_timetable
```

you can use `a.findAll('tag')[index]` or find a spesific class like `a.findAll('p',attrs={'class' : 'booking-item-destination'})[1]`

OUTPUT:

```
[{'ARRIVAL PORT': u'NAPOLI Porta di Massa', 'FERRY TYPE': u'TRAGHETTO', 
'DEPARTURE DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019', 'ARRIVAL TIME': u'08:00', 'DEPARTURE TIME': u'06:40', 'DEPARTURE PORT': u'CAPRI', 'ARRIVAL DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019'},
 {'ARRIVAL PORT': u'NAPOLI Porta di Massa', 'FERRY TYPE': u'TMV', 'DEPARTURE DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019', 'ARRIVAL TIME': u'11:20', 'DEPARTURE TIME': u'10:20', 'DEPARTURE PORT': u'CAPRI', 'ARRIVAL DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019'}, 
{'ARRIVAL PORT': u'NAPOLI Porta di Massa', 'FERRY TYPE': u'TRAGHETTO', 'DEPARTURE DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019', 'ARRIVAL TIME': u'12:25', 'DEPARTURE TIME': u'11:00', 'DEPARTURE PORT': u'CAPRI', 'ARRIVAL DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019'}, 
{'ARRIVAL PORT': u'NAPOLI Porta di Massa', 'FERRY TYPE': u'TMV', 'DEPARTURE DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019', 'ARRIVAL TIME': u'16:25', 'DEPARTURE TIME': u'15:35', 'DEPARTURE PORT': u'CAPRI', 'ARRIVAL DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019'},
 {'ARRIVAL PORT': u'NAPOLI Porta di Massa', 'FERRY TYPE': u'TRAGHETTO', 'DEPARTURE DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019', 'ARRIVAL TIME': u'19:00', 'DEPARTURE TIME': u'17:40', 'DEPARTURE PORT': u'CAPRI', 'ARRIVAL DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019'}, 
{'ARRIVAL PORT': u'NAPOLI Porta di Massa', 'FERRY TYPE': u'TMV', 'DEPARTURE DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019', 'ARRIVAL TIME': u'20:45', 'DEPARTURE TIME': u'20:05', 'DEPARTURE PORT': u'CAPRI', 'ARRIVAL DATE': u'Lun\xa025/02/2019'}]
```

Comment: To extract dates correctly split text. For example `a.findAll('p')[0].text[-10:]`